# How to add line break after input element with CSS?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm consuming a service which returns dynamic HTML with a series of labels and inputs e.g.

```css
input:after {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

<label for="country">Country</label>
<input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
```

I want the form to be formatted as follows:

[image]

But it does not work. Surrounding the labels and inputs with a div is NOT possible as this is dynamic HTML returned to me by a service.

Any ideas how this can be achieved only through CSS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replaced elements including `<img>`, `<object>`, **`<input>`**, and`<textarea>` **...** do not have `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

As a workaround, you could set the line break on the `<label>` element.

```css
label:before {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" />

<label for="country">Country</label>
<input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
```

Comment: Is it possible to have fixed width labels so that we can align labels text to the right as shown in the capture ?

Comment: I would recommend to add extra markup to do that, i.e. wrap the fields into `<div>` tags, quick example here http://jsfiddle.net/gxvd50cy/

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning that replaced elements don't have pseudo elements. I checked many examples for adding a line break with CSS trying to figure out why it doesn't work, until finally landing on this page. In case no labels used on the form, a span element could be inserted between the input elements to achieve the line break.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that

```
label, input {
    display: inline-block;
}
label {
    width: 20%
}
input {
    width: 70%
}
```

Adapt the value as you need.
http://jsfiddle.net/sj4jrkLq/3/